# How to ask a user to select object from run-time given list?

Tags: matlab, dynamic, user-input

I am writing a script that needs the user to select the subdirectory on which to work.

Here to point where I'm stuck:

```
curr_dir = dir(pwd);

% Select only subdirectories
dirs = {curr_dir([curr_dir(:).isdir]).name}';
dirs(ismember(dirs,{'.','..'})) = [];

% Ask the user which one to use
dir_selected = 0;
while dir_selected == 0;
    selection = ; % <------------- INSERT HERE MISSING CODE
    if length(selection) == 1
        dir_selected = 1;
    elseif length(selection) > 1
        fprintf('\nPlease enter only one value\n');
    elseif selection > length(dirs)
        fprintf('\nPlease enter a valid value\n');
    else
        fprintf('\nPlease enter a value\n');
    end
end

path_files = dirs(selection);
```

I need to list to the user the present subdirectories (together with their index) and ask the user to type in the index of the folder he want to work in.

I have seen examples with both `input()` and `prompt()`, but most assumes that the message is static. Is it possible to have a dynamically generated message/prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry to everyone, I found how to solve the problem.

I use the following code:

```
fprintf('\nPlease select the desired subdirectory:\n');
for i = 1:length(dirs)
    fprintf('%i: %s\n',i,dirs{i});
end
selection = input('Which is the desired subdirectory?: ');
```